# NodeMCU error connecting to WiFi

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I have tried a blink on the NodeMCU working ok, but when doing basic connection to WiFi I get this error:

> init.lua:4: attempt to concatenate global 'gw' (a nil value)

this is the connection

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("wifi-name","password") 
ip, nm, gw=wifi.sta.getip()
print("\nIP Info:\nIP Address: "..ip.." \nNetmask: "..nm.." \nGateway Addr: "..gw.."\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NodeMCU many functions are asynchronous (assume this to be the default). Hence, calling `wifi.sta.config` isn't blocking your main thread and consequently your device most likely isn't connected to WiFi by the time you invoke `wifi.sta.getip`.

If you have a firmware from the `dev` branch you can use the [WiFi event monitor](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/wifi/#wifistaeventmonreg) to fix that:

```
wifi.sta.eventMonReg(wifi.STA_GOTIP, function() 
  ip, nm, gw=wifi.sta.getip()
  print("\nIP Info:\nIP Address: "..ip.." \nNetmask: "..nm.." \nGateway Addr: "..gw.."\n")
end)
```

I documented a more basic timer-callback driven approach [in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/marcelstoer/63ce6e6d78cef435d2ec):

```
wifiReady = 0

function configureWiFi()
    wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
    wifi.sta.config(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS)
    wifi.sta.connect()
    tmr.alarm(WIFI_ALARM_ID, 1000, 1, wifi_watch)
end
-- while NOT connected to WiFi you blink a LED, see below
function wifi_watch()
    -- 0: STATION_IDLE,
    -- 1: STATION_CONNECTING,
    -- 2: STATION_WRONG_PASSWORD,
    -- 3: STATION_NO_AP_FOUND,
    -- 4: STATION_CONNECT_FAIL,
    -- 5: STATION_GOT_IP.
    status = wifi.sta.status()
    if status == 5 then
        -- only do something if the status actually changed
        -- you could of course combine these two 'if's but it's more explicit for this gist
        if wifiReady == 0 then
            wifiReady = 1
            print("WiFi: connected")
            turnWiFiLedOn()
            -- do something
        end
    else
        wifiReady = 0
        print("WiFi: (re-)connecting")
        turnWiFiLedOnOff()
        wifi.sta.connect()
    end
end
```