# Socket Connection in NodeMCU Lua works as snippet, not from init.lua

Tags: sockets, lua, nodemcu

I have the following code

```
conn = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)  
conn:on("sent", function(sck,c) 
   print("Sent")
   sck:close() 
   end)

conn:on("connection", function(sck,c) 
   print("Connected..")
   sck:send("test") 
   end)

 conn:connect(9090, "192.168.1.89")
 print("Send data.")
```

This works fine when run as a snippet in ESPlorer, IE run live interpreter. I see the output "Connected.." and "Sent", and the message appears on the sever. When it is part of either the init.lua, or my mcu-temp.lua I don't even see the "Connected.." message.

The connection to WIFI is OK, and the board isn't reset between trying it "live" and from the file. I'm really stuck as to why it works OK one way and not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The connection to WIFI is OK

I seriously doubt that. If you run from ESPlorer then yes, but not when you reboot the device.

Connecting to an AP takes a few seconds normally. You need to wait until it's connected until you can continue with the startup sequence. Remember: with NodeMCU most operations are asynchronous and event-driven, `wifi.sta.connect()` does NOT block.

Here's a startup sequence I borrowed, and adapted, from https://cknodemcu.wordpress.com/.

```
SSID = <tbd>
PASSWORD = <tbd>

function startup()
    local conn = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)  
    conn:on("sent", function(sck, c) 
       print("Sent")
       sck:close() 
    end)

    conn:on("connection", function(sck, c) 
       print("Connected..")
       sck:send("test") 
    end)

    conn:connect(9090, "192.168.1.89")
    print("Sent data.")
end

print("setting up WiFi")
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config(SSID,PASSWORD)
wifi.sta.connect()
tmr.alarm(1, 1000, 1, function() 
    if wifi.sta.getip() == nil then 
        print("IP unavaiable, Waiting...") 
    else 
        tmr.stop(1)
        print("Config done, IP is "..wifi.sta.getip())
        print("You have 5 seconds to abort startup")
        print("Waiting...")
        tmr.alarm(0, 5000, 0, startup)
    end 
 end)
```

Just two days ago I answered nearly the same question here on SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37495955/131929 for an alternative solution.

Comment: The init script is a lot better than the one I had, so I'm definitely using that. Although it's not solved the issue. I've run 'nc -l 192.168.1.84 9090' on the target host, as well as the original nodejs app that I've written, and I don't get the connection message from the socket events.

Comment: I apologise, it has worked! Firewall rules after restarting the VM was to blame.